# I am having a data insertion problem in tables "pm_feature_id" is primary key from table and it interlinked with other 2 tables

Tags: postgresql

I am having a data insertion problem in tables "pm_feature_id" is primary key from table and it interlinked with other 2 tables.the primary key is auto increment and it declared as variable, i am inserting the data in tables by using   below the code"

i am inserting the data but i am trying to return the data "pm_feature_name,pm_component_id" by using select statement

```
-- FUNCTION: project.fn_insert_features(character varying, integer, character varying, character varying, integer, integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION project.fn_insert_features(character varying, integer, character varying, character varying, integer, integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION project.fn_insert_features(
    featurename character varying,
    compntid integer,
    descrptn character varying,
    helpfilename character varying,
    mediatypeid integer,
    accntemplyid integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(pm_feature_name character varying, pm_component_id integer)
    LANGUAGE "sql"

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
     ROWS 1000 

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   v_id integer;

BEGIN
    Insert into project.pm_features
        (pm_feature_name,pm_component_id,pm_description)values (featurename,compntid,descrptn)
        RETURNING pm_feature_id INTO v_id;


     Insert into project.pm_help_files
        (component_feature_id,help_file_name, media_type_id)values (v_id,helpfilename,mediatypeid);

    Insert into project.pm_point_of_contacts
     (component_feature_id,pm_account_employee_id)values(v_id,accntemplyid);

    select pm_feature_name,pm_component_id from project.pm_features

    END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION project.fn_insert_features(character varying, integer, character varying, character varying, integer, integer)
    OWNER TO pattesaadmin;
```

> **ERROR** ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer" LINE 21:    v_id integer;
>                    ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 637

Comment: aren't you forgetting a `;` at `    select pm_feature_name,pm_component_id from project.pm_features`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION project.fn_insert_features(
    featurename character varying,
    compntid integer,
    descrptn character varying,
    helpfilename character varying,
    mediatypeid integer,
    accntemplyid integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(pm_feature_name character varying, pm_component_id integer)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
     ROWS 1000 

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   v_id integer;

BEGIN
    Insert into project.pm_features
        (pm_feature_name,pm_component_id,pm_description)values (featurename,compntid,descrptn)
        RETURNING pm_feature_id INTO v_id;


     Insert into project.pm_help_files
        (component_feature_id,help_file_name, media_type_id)values (v_id,helpfilename,mediatypeid);

    Insert into project.pm_point_of_contacts
     (component_feature_id,pm_account_employee_id)values(v_id,accntemplyid);

    return query select pm_features.pm_feature_name, pm_features.pm_component_id from project.pm_features;

    END;
$BODY$;


ALTER FUNCTION project.fn_insert_features(character varying, integer, character varying, character varying, integer, integer)
    OWNER TO pattesaadmin;
```

Note that I changed "sql" to plpgsql and added "return query" in front of the select statement and a semicolon at the end of the statement.
Hopefully this will be enough, I don't have the table descriptions to test completely.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: thank you Bjami,but i am getting error while executing the code in postgressql    --ERROR:  column reference "pm_feature_name" is ambiguous
LINE 1: select pm_feature_name,pm_component_id from project.pm_featu...
               ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  select pm_feature_name,pm_component_id from project.pm_features
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function project.fn_insert_features(character varying,integer,character varying,character varying,integer,integer) line 17 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 42702

Comment: Ok.  Try now.  I changed the select statement.  The compiler didn't know if it was referring to a column in the return table of the function or the column in the table in the select statement.

Comment: yeah its working in postgresql,thank you  Bjarni Ragnarsson.in web api the data not returning the values,in postman showing error : not found.